# Decision problem concerning factors of a special family of polynomials.

Tags: nt.number-theory

Does there exist an algorithm (of any complexity) for the following problem?

Given: $p(x)\in{\Bbb Z}[x]$.

Question: Does there exist a polynomial $q(x)= 1 - \sum_i^m x^{n_i}$ such that $p|q$?
The variables  $n_1,\ldots,n_m$ represent distinct positive integers.

Comment: I'm still interested in what you wrote!  I hope I can persuade you to undelete your answer!!

Comment: if $m$ is fixed, then it does exist (but it is hardly what are asking about)

Comment: @ Fedor Yes, Rassilon had posted what looked like a nice comment explaining the $m$-fixed algorithm, but (sadly!) deleted it when I clarified my question (before I'd finished reading it carefully).

Comment: well, let me explain (maybe different) $m$-fixed algorithm. If all roots of $p$ belong to the unit circle, then they are roots of 1, their powers have only finite number of values, and the rest is clear. If $p$ have a root $a$, $|a|<1$, then we have a priori upper bound for $n_1$ ($n_1 < n_2 < \dots$), else $\sum a^{n_i}$ is too small), for fixed $m_1$ we have upper bound for $n_2$ and so on. Then we have a tree of possible values of $n_1$, $n_2$ and so on, it is of bounded depth, so the check will be finished in finite time.